# Complex integration on a closed curve

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Find $\oint_C \frac{dz}{z-2}$ on the square $C$ with vertices $\pm2\pm 2i$ .

As there is a pole at $z=2$, I removed it by taking a semicircle of small radius $r$ about $2$ and the integral on the resulting curve should be zero. The integeral on the semicircle should be $\pi i$. When $r$ tends to zero, the required integral should be $\pi i$. I am not sure if I am doing this right.

Comment: What have you tried?  What has you stuck?  Do you have an idea what to do when a pole is on the path of integration?

Comment: .
As there is a pole at $z=2$ , I removed it by taking a semicircle of small radius $r$ about $2$  and the integral on the resulting curve should be zero. Integral on the semicircle should be $\pi i$. When $r$ tends to zero , the required integral should be $\pi i$. I am not sure if I do this right.

Comment: I'd add that to your question, so that it becomes subject matter that can be discussed.

Comment: what sort of integral? in a strict sense the integral doesn't exist since it diverges at 2. If you want the PV integral, can you edit to reflect this?

Comment: @MarkJoshi nope the integral does not diverge at 2. Just like the integral of log function does not diverge at 0.

Comment: the integral of 1/x diverges at 0 and that is the correct analogue not log x.

Comment: @MarkJoshi nope , I am talking about log function. Though log diverges to negative infinity at 0 but the area covered by it in (0,1) is finite.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokhotski%E2%80%93Plemelj_theorem

Answer (score 1):

The integral along one eighth of the contour is
$$\int_{2+\epsilon i}^{2+2i}\frac{dz}{z-2}=\int_\epsilon^2\frac{i\,dy}{iy}=\ln2-\ln\epsilon\to\infty\ \hbox{as $\epsilon\to0^+$}\ ,$$
so this integral, and therefore the whole integral, diverges.

If you are looking for a principal value, or if you are using some other definition for convergence of an improper integral, you need to state this clearly in your question.